# Simple select sql query to retrieve the specific value for a key with key value pairs saved as varchar in a column

Tags: sql, string, select, key-value

Input:

- Table Name  - Example
- Column Name - Value    DataType - varchar  Length - -1

Data stored as

```
[{"Key":"ABC","Value":"1"},{"Key":"DEF","Value":"2"},{"Key":"GHI","Value""3"}]
```

Can anyone of you please provide a select query to get the value of Key - DEF (some example)

```
Select Value 
From Example 
Where Key = -- something like this
```

Comment: `Select Value 
From Example 
Where Key = 'DEF'`?

Comment: Above statement didn't worked. Can you modify the way it works and need not be something i have provided in the question. Thanks..!!